# Get category of a discussion from discussion folder using /jquery/spservices/

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

below is the code for the same which shows an error of status 500, at alert status it shows error. let me know how to do that

```
var _query = ""+discussionTitle+"";
             alert(_query);

$().SPServices({
    operation: 'GetListItems',
    async: false,
    listName: '',
    CAMLQueryOptions: "",
    CAMLViewFields: "",
    CAMLQuery: _query,
      completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                   **alert(Status);**
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
            alert("Hi");
          var NewCategory=$(this).attr('Category');
          alert(NewCategory);

                        });                
                    }

        });
```